# disable an item in md-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, md-autocomplete

We have a situation where we turned a md-input-container with a md-select / md-option to a md-autocomplete.  In the md-select/md-option we were able to have a ng-disabled property on both the md-select and md-option.   For the md-autocomplete we have not found a way to use a ng-disabled at the option/item level.  We are using it on the md-autocomplete but need to disable options in the drop down once they are selected too.

Is there a way to do this using md-autocomplete?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured out a solution? I need the same thing. I can't seem to find a way of preventing the click event for an item

Comment: No we couldn't figure it out so just left it as a md-select/md-option. Sorry.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745185/1134132. I believe that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

On md-item-template use something like this:

```
ng-click="item.mail==''?$event.stopPropagation():''"
```